# Comparing two unknown list in Python

Tags: python, list, if-statement, return

How can I iterate throughout two unknown lists with an unknown amount of sublists and unknown elements. What I am looking to do is to compare them and return `True` if they are the same length and `False` if not the same length and not the same type of element in the specific index.

My code so far:

```
def similarList(list1,list2):
    if len(list1)!=len(list2):
        return False
    else:
        if len(list1)>1 and len(list2)>1:
```

This is where I am not sure how to compare each element of the `list1` and `list2`.

Example:

```
similarList([0],[4])
```

True

```
similarList([3.9],[8])
```

False

```
similarList([[4,5,6],4] , [[2,3,4],'a'])
```

False because `4` is an integer and `'a'` is a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might do something like this:

```
def similarList(list1, list2):
    if len(list1) != len(list2):
        return False
    return all(isinstance(a, type(b)) for a, b in zip(list1, list2))
```

the `isinstance(a, type(b))` bit could probably use a little tweaking depending on your use-case.  e.g. if you want to assert that they are exactly the same type, `type(a) is type(b)` would be more appropriate.  If you don't know which would be the subclass, then `isinstance(a, type(b)) or isinstance(b, type(a))` might be what you want.

FYI: There is a certain amount of ambiguity in the "same type" criterion -- e.g. consider `'foo'` and `u'foo'`.  They're not the same type.  They won't even pass the most permissive `isinstance` check that I outlined above, but for a lot of applications, they're interchangeable. . .

Answer (score 0):

You can use `type` and recursion to check again in `lists`:

```
def similarList(list1,list2):
    if len(list1)!=len(list2):
       return False
    else:
        for item1, item2 in zip(list1, list2):
            if type(item1) != type(item2):
                return False
            elif isinstance((item1, item2), list):
               return similarList(item1,item2)

    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you're only dealing with lists (not tuples), and you want to be strict about type comparisons:

```
def similar_list(list1, list2):
    if not isinstance(list1, list) or not isinstance(list2, list):
        return False
    if len(list1) != len(list2):
        return False
    for a, b in zip(list1, list2):
        if isinstance(a, list):
            if not similar_list(a, b):
                return False
        if type(a) is not type(b):
            return False
    return True
```